# POST data in Header to the web server in android?

Tags: android, http-post

I am making a simple login form in android in which i need to send the os-name and version number via Header to the server using web-service api that i have. I am a beginner in android the methods such as addHeader etc have deprecated. Can someone please help me figure out how can add 
Here is my  code:

LOGIN : I want to POST the os name, os_version fields in header to the server . how can i do that? Below is my code

```
  String user = editText_name.getText().toString();
    String pass =editText_pass.getText().toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("user_name",user);
    jsonObject.put("password",pass);


    String url = WsUtils.BASE_URL+WsUtils.WS_LOGIN;


    if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
        new sendJsonData().execute(getPostDataString(jsonObject),url);

    }else Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> sendJsonData()::>>

```
 public  class sendJsonData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String Jsonresponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("please wait");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String Jsondata = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[1]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");


            OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(Jsondata);

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            Log.e("json", Jsondata);


            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Jsonresponse = convertStreamToString(in);


            return Jsonresponse;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("response", Jsonresponse);

    }


}
```

> getPostDataString()-->`

```
public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
URL url = new URL(YOUR_URL);
try {
    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("os-name", Build.VERSION.RELEASE);  // 6.x.x
    myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You may set other property by setRequestProperty(String key, String value).

Comment: so if i were to send the os name of the application to the server as a field what key should i use in the setrequestproperty() method?

Comment: os name? Is it a custom data you want to send to server?

Comment: yaa! actually i need to send the os name to the server along with data username and password. but the os name is to be sent in header. how to do that?

Comment: If it is a custom field, you can use your specific name to be the key, such as "os-name".
However, you cannot directly get the os name but you can get the SDK version by Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.

Comment: Update: Use Build.VERSION.RELEASE would be better. // result: 6.x.x;


Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is used for version comparison.

Comment: please check the update above, and make sure server side can read the property `os-name`. As mentioned, it is something like 5.x.x, 6.x.x; but not Lollipop (5.x.x), Marshmallow (6.x.x), Nougat (7.x.x)

Comment: I wrote this code::::>>public String osName = fields[Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + 1].getName();
    public static String OS_NAME = "os";   urlConnection.setRequestProperty(OS_NAME,osName); and i got the following response:::>E/response: {"settings":{"success":"0","message":"Please enter a value for the os field.","fields":[]},"data":[]}

Comment: what is the key string value your server is trying to get? it seems not `os`

Comment: The name is os only! is there any other method?

Comment: How about if try to remove Content-Type : myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", .....

Comment: does not help! :(

Comment: webservice :::  http://108.170.62.151/projects/kinderbucks/WS/parent_login?

Comment: ok i have tried, here is my findings:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
which means somethings you have done in your method getPostDataString()
user_name=user&password=pass&os=Marshmallow&os_version=Marshmallow&app_version=1.0

Comment: And result will be "message": "You have entered wrong user name or password. Please try again."
So server is getting the os and os_version in body but not header?

Comment: so does that mean i can add these details in the jsonobject only and not in the headers?

Comment: i did not understand you!!

Comment: yes, exactly, you may try it with your raw user_name and password

Comment: I meant: I have tried to send 
`user_name=user&password=pass&os=Marshmallow&os_version=Marsh‌​mallow&app_version=1‌​.0`
and then i get 
`"message": "You have entered wrong user name or password. Please try again."`

Comment: ohh okay got it!@ i guess i will have to pass it in body only

Comment: yup, you can try it yourself. Actually, custom header should be avoided.
ref: 
`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html`
and
`http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt`

Comment: can u please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786168/listview-does-not-appear-in-my-fragment-created-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to android, and just need a standard POST mechanism to work, Try [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). Its by Square and is trusted across the globe.

Recommending you to use it, cause in the beginner level, you are prone to make mistakes, but if you use a library for the same you skip to write all the boiler plate code and reduce chances of bugs too.

Comment: Actually i have been assigned to do this task by using headers. So can not use Retrofits. Can u please suggest code for it?